# No route to host, not able to ping

Tags: networking, router, ipv4

I am attempting to reach the admin web page of a router connected directly to my laptop via Ethernet cable. The router (a [TP-Link WR700N](https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/TL-WR700N.html#specifications)) is brand new, just taken out of the box. It is plugged in and the LED status light indicates normal operation. The default IP address of the admin page is 192.168.0.254.

My laptop is running Linux and my interface name is eth0. With the router on and connected directly to my laptop by Ethernet patch cable, I ran this command to set an address:

```
 ip addr add 192.168.0.10/24 dev eth0
```

I show the interface as UP with the expected address of 192.168.0.10.

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:b9:5b:9a:de:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.10/24 scope global eth0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, when I try to reach the admin page of the router at http://192.168.0.254 Firefox says "Unable to connect". When I try to ping that address I get "Destination Host Unreachable".

The command `curl -I http://192.168.0.254` returns the error "failed to connect to 192.168.0.254 port 80: no route to host".

For troubleshooting, I have changed out the cable and I have done a "factory reset" on the router (even though it is brand new). The router LED goes through the expected stages during reset.

I also tried setting the connection using NetworkManager in KDE (manual IP address). In that case `ip a` gives this output:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:b9:5b:9a:de:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.10/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, the error messages remain the same. Finally, I tried setting the connection using NetworkManager in automatic / DHCP mode, but eth0 does not get an address.

Have I overlooked something in making the connection? Have I missed any troubleshooting steps? Or can I conclude this device is defective?

UPDATE: I added `tcpdump`, `ip route` and additional info below:

```
# connect cable:

root@host1 [/home/joe1]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 23:ba:53:24:82:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:d2:10:2c:2f:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

# network manager cannot obtain an IP address, set it manually:

root@host1 [/home/joe1]# ip a add 192.168.0.10/24 brd 192.168.0.255 dev eth0

root@host1 [/home/joe1]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 23:ba:53:24:82:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.10/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:d2:10:2c:2f:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

# device's manual states that 192.168.0.254 is the admin page IP address

root@host1 [/home/joe1]# ping 192.168.0.254
PING 192.168.0.254 (192.168.0.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.0.254 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 67ms
pipe 4

root@host1 [/home/joe1]# ip route
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.10

root@host1 [/home/joe1]# tcpdump -vvv
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
17:42:45.941767 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 32, id 14813, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 316)
    0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2 (oui Unknown), length 288, xid 0xed64d8be, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
        Client-Ethernet-Address c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2 (oui Unknown)
        Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1024
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 10:
            Subnet-Mask, Default-Gateway, Vendor-Option, Netbios-Name-Server
            Netbios-Node, Netbios-Scope, Domain-Name-Server, Static-Route
            Classless-Static-Route, Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft
            Hostname Option 12, length 6: "WR700N"
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 9: "MSFT 98^@_"
            Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2
            END Option 255, length 0
17:42:49.941806 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 32, id 14813, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 316)
    0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2 (oui Unknown), length 288, xid 0xed64d8be, secs 4, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
        Client-Ethernet-Address c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2 (oui Unknown)
        Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1024
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 10:
            Subnet-Mask, Default-Gateway, Vendor-Option, Netbios-Name-Server
            Netbios-Node, Netbios-Scope, Domain-Name-Server, Static-Route
            Classless-Static-Route, Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft
            Hostname Option 12, length 6: "WR700N"
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 9: "MSFT 98^@_"
            Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2
            END Option 255, length 0
17:42:56.941934 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 32, id 14813, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 316)
    0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2 (oui Unknown), length 288, xid 0xed64d8be, secs 11, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
        Client-Ethernet-Address c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2 (oui Unknown)
        Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1024
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 10:
            Subnet-Mask, Default-Gateway, Vendor-Option, Netbios-Name-Server
            Netbios-Node, Netbios-Scope, Domain-Name-Server, Static-Route
            Classless-Static-Route, Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft
            Hostname Option 12, length 6: "WR700N"
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 9: "MSFT 98^@_"
            Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2
            END Option 255, length 0
17:42:57.480505 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 59726, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 73)
    host1.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: [bad udp cksum 0xa1f4 -> 0x3289!] 0 [2q] PTR (QM)? _ipps._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipp._tcp.local. (45)
17:43:12.942038 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 32, id 14813, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 316)
    0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2 (oui Unknown), length 288, xid 0xed64d8be, secs 27, Flags [none] (0x0000)
        Client-Ethernet-Address c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2 (oui Unknown)
        Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Discover
            MSZ Option 57, length 2: 1024
            Parameter-Request Option 55, length 10:
            Subnet-Mask, Default-Gateway, Vendor-Option, Netbios-Name-Server
            Netbios-Node, Netbios-Scope, Domain-Name-Server, Static-Route
            Classless-Static-Route, Classless-Static-Route-Microsoft
            Hostname Option 12, length 6: "WR700N"
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 9: "MSFT 98^@_"
            Client-ID Option 61, length 7: ether c4:e9:84:64:a7:b2
            END Option 255, length 0
^C
5 packets captured
5 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

UPDATE 2: `tcpdump` shows that the device is asking for an IP address as a DHCP client. So I plugged the Ethernet cable into my dhcp server, it got an address, but I was not able to connect to the admin pages using that address. Clearly the manual for this device is wrong or misleading. I have two of these devices, both are new, both have now been "factory reset, and I cannot get either one of them to work.

```
Firefox http://192.168.1.203/
The connection has timed out
The server at 192.168.1.203 is taking too long to respond.

# ping 192.168.1.203
PING 192.168.1.203 (192.168.1.203) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.203: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.226 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.203: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.200 ms
```

Comment: Why don't you try DHCP for interface configuration? The router should have DHCP server up and running by default.

Comment: @Tomek - as mentioned, I did try DHCP. However, it did not work and I did not expect it to work because the default configuration of the router has its DHCP server turned off (according to the user guide). However, I used the static IP address suggested in the user guide and surely I would have expected the static IP to work. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Please add the output of the commands: `ip addr` and `ip route`

Comment: In the first listing there is no broadcast address. This will likely prevent arp from working. In the second listing there is incorrect broadcast address (192.168.5.255 where I would expect 192.168.0.255) and this is likely also affecting arp.

Comment: Run `tcpdump` to see what happens on the network.

Comment: Question updated. I fixed my typo in the broadcast address. Because the laptop in question has no network connectivity, I am typing all the command output by hand and I made a typo in that instance. Fixed now. I will report back later today with the results of `tcpdump` and `ip route` (`ip a` is already listed and the typo is now fixed). Thanks.

Comment: The question has been updated with the requested info. Thanks.